# Есть ли виртуальное окружение в C?

Tags: c

Есть ли в C виртуальные окружения аналогичные тем, что есть в `python` (anaconda environment, virtual env), `golang` (go-mod режим)? Как они реализуются?

Comment: chroot? cgroups?
А в самом языке — нет,  точно нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Менеджер зависимостей в C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117667/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Обилие минусов действительно непонятно. Но и вопрос сам по себе тоже как-то непонятен. Уточните в чем именно проблема, чего вы хотите добиться? Какие моменты виртуальных окружений вам нужны?

Comment: Обясните для тех, кто не пользовался go/python, что за виртуальные окружения?

Comment: виртуальное окружение для питона или подобных языков это грубо говоря просто скрипт, который при запуске прописывает правильно пути к бинарникам и библиотекам (правит PATH в самом простом случае) и таким образом можно работать с нужной версией питона/библиотек. В с/с++ это называется докер. Ну или gcc-config, для тех, кто умеет

Comment: На винде еще можно несколько копий msys2 поставить... Я минус не ставил, но раз вопрос про С, имхо, стоит его писать так будто с питоном/го читатели не знакомы.

Comment: если программист на си не знает базового питона, то у меня большие вопросы к такому програмисту.