# Менеджер зависимостей в C

Tags: c, контроль-версий, зависимости

Есть ли в c менеджеры зависимостей типо как в pip, go mod? Или вендринг только?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандарт такое не регламентирует. Все отдается на откуп разработчиков компиляторов/тулов. По факту есть [cmake](https://cmake.org/), [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/), [vspkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg). Как по мне, то любой дистрибутив линукса также есть менеджером зависимостей. Просто очень навороченным и с своими странностями:)

Comment: Про линукс... так можно далеко зайти

Comment: https://conan.io/